# How to run function when "viewDidLoad" is called while using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to run a function when the app finish loading up, like `viewDidLoad`, but I'm using SwiftUI now and I have no `viewDidLoad`. How can I do this now?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                self.exampleFunction()

                Text(" ......  ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to take some information from that function and present it in the text. But the way I'm doing it is wrong. It's not building.

Comment: You really need to show more code. We can't duplicate your issue - but worse, your issue doesn't make sense. `viewDidLoad` is part of `UIKit` and **not** part of `SwiftUI`. (You could try `onAppear` and `onDisappear` but I think that's not the issue.) What's your model? Are you using `@State` variables? How can you do **what* - specifically? Sorry, but for now I actually do have to downvote this question. PLEASE, be more specific. What you posted *can* be done, but apprearantly not how you are trying to do. And try to understand... `SwiftUI` is *reactive* by nature, not the *source* or much.

Comment: @dfd when I was using UIKit, and I want to run a function that I created when the app finish loading, I was writing it under the viewDidLoad. Now that there is no viewDidLoad, how is it done? thanks!

Comment: Yes, understood. And part of what I call "paradigm change' involves understanding that you only have `onAppear` because that's all you get. (Just noted, I didn't downvote and won't.) Details.... **what** are you used to do in `viewDidLoad`? And remember, *that* isn't "reactive", it's 'after-the-fact". I'm guessing you need to understand "reactive" - I'm barely grasping some details - along with explaining what your model is (or maybe just the model state). What function dod you run 8after* `viewDidLoad`, and what does it do?

Comment: "and I want to run a function that I created when the app finish loading" But function? What is it that you do? It may be that `viewDidLoad` was never the appropriate place for it.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `.onAppear { ... }` to execute arbitrary code when a view appears:

```swift
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text(" ......  ")
                }.onAppear { self.exampleFunction() }
```

Comment: Good answer. But does this fit for all circumstances like in `UIKit`? It sounds to me - and I'm probably wrong - that the OP is thinking too much like `UIKit` coding. For example, let's say you wish to load a NSURL content from `onAppear`. Will this work? `snapper` is simply **not** equatable to `viewDidLoad`. Two different stacks, two different APIs. EDIT: And do not forget that an  - `onAppear` closure will happen *every time* that view appears. `viewDidLoad` happens only every time the UIView... was loaded.

Answer (score 13):

Fully updated for Xcode 11.2, Xcode 5.0 
I think the `viewDidLoad()` just equal to implement in the body closure. 
SwiftUI gives us equivalents to UIKit’s `viewDidAppear()` and `viewDidDisappear()` in the form of `onAppear()` and `onDisappear()`. You can attach any code to these two events that you want, and SwiftUI will execute them when they occur.

As an example, this creates two views that use `onAppear()` and `onDisappear()` to print messages, with a navigation link to move between the two:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            print("ContentView appeared!")
        }.onDisappear {
            print("ContentView disappeared!")
        }
    }
}
```

ref:https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear

Comment: but we can't call api (network request) in body closure.

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to run something after the app launches and has nothing to do with a specific view you can add code in two different places...

In AppDelegate.swift, the first function is called after the App launches...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // ******** Run your function here **********

        return true
    }
```

Or in, SceneDelegate.swift, the first function actually sets the root view to the original ContentView...

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
            self.window = window

        // ******** Add code here before root view is shown **********

            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        // ******** Add code here after root view is shown **********

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `init()` instead. I think `onApear()` is not an alternative to `viewDidLoad()`. Because onApear is called when your view is being appeared. Since your view can be appear multiple times it conflicts with `viewDidLoad` which is called once.

Imagine having a `TabView`. By swiping through pages onApear() is being called multiple times. However viewDidLoad() is called just once.

```swift
struct TeamInfoView: View {
 var myText:String
    init() {
      myText = function()
    }
    .....
}
```

After having initialized it's time to use the value of the string:

```swift
var body: some View {
   
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text(myText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```